# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dns

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell M3800.

I am having problems connecting to the Internet.

I get`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG` in my browser when trying to navigate to any site, but I am able to navigate to any site by using its IP.

So, for example, I am able to navigate to `google.com` by using `http://173.194.121.16`. So I think somewhere my DNS settings got messed up.

Any pointer on resolving this issue is appreciated. Please, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Can you resolve google.com using `nslookup google.com`?

Comment: @the_Seppi nslookup for any server was not working. I tried that.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was. When I ran the following command `sudo resolvconf -u` I got this error:

```
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`
```

I solved this error by deleting `/etc/resolv.conf` and recreating the symbolic link. You can do that using the following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

This resolved the DNS error I was getting.

for Ubuntu 20.04 and above, just

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Can you provide a description of what this symbolic link is needed for?

Comment: Wow! this was so simple! I used to boot into recovery environment and enable networking for so long!

Comment: Hi, I tried the command as above. Then I type "ping cnn.com". the return is "ping: unknown host cnn.com".    I type "ping google.com", the return is sth as " 64 bytes from dfw06s48-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.194.110):  icmp_seq=10  ttl=53 time=31.7ms

Comment: From what directory I should execute this command?

Comment: @Permana you can execute this command from `/etc` directory

Comment: @Amrish: If you remove the two dots before /run, it can be run from everywhere. :)

Comment: +1, Worked also for Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell Precision 5520

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 14.04 Dell Precision M4800

Comment: +1 This approach worked for Ubuntu 16.04 also. My problem was the following.
* I used to get "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG" error in chrome and equivalent in Firefox.
* Tor browser was working okay.
* 'ping 8.8.8.8' was working okay.
This solution fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems I need to run it once in a while for my internet to work. Any solution to that?

Comment: sudo resolvconf -u doesn't show me anything

Comment: Thanks, I used to edit /etc/resolv.conf every time. I started getting this error after installing protonVPN on my machine.

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Say yes to "prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?"

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: It worked. What a stupid bug :-)

Comment: I answered no to the mentioned question and did not rebooted, but my problem still got solved immediately by this command. (Ubuntu 19.10, Chromium 80.0.)

Comment: resolvconf is not installed

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using NordVPN and using openvpn via terminal. I resolved this problem by importing VPN configuration file to Ubuntu Network UI. You can  go to Settings -> Network. There will be VPN section, press add and then import file. Choose one of the downloaded .ovpn files from NordVPN. Then when you try to connect it seems to automatically fix DNS issue for some reason. :)

Actually that's what I expected because sometimes UI solutions are more stable than running Terminal commands.

Comment: I'm not using VPN