# After the upgrade to 16.04 LTS, internet won't work

Tags: internet, 16.04

I have upgraded to 16.04 LTS (from 15.10). Wi-Fi and LAN both shows connected, but internet is not working.

I have done re-installation of Broadcom wi-fi drivers (through additional drivers), restarted network-manager services. But problem not solved.

Comment: When you boot up using liveCD does it work ?

Comment: Yes, it works while on LiveCD boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a DNS problem...

Check if you are able to connect to your router IP. (if you can, it probably is)

Check your ifconfig for DNS and Gateway info.

If it is a DNS problem, recheck your network configuration on DHCP and/or use a static lan address with your router/dhcp server as 1st DNS, and other DNS servers following.

Comment: That's it. Problem was with the resolve.conf.  solved it following http://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04#