# Internet problems after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, upgrade, ftp

I am using Firefox 48.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, some internet settings have gone wrong.

1 : It is not possible to connect to `www.bahn.de`

> www.bahn.de : Request Timeout
>
> The server timed out while waiting for the browser's request
>
> Reference #2.5c3d1602.1471088878.0

2 : It is not possible to transfer files via ftp to a server using konqueror.

Comment: I connect to `www.bahn.de` with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing could be a DNS problem. Check your router and/ or network settings. Maybe try by checking your resolvconf like here: [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04#)
The second thing could be a bug, have you tried with a different program? Maybe even the terminal client?

You can try more test using some procedures recommended here: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/testing-network-services-with-netcat/