# 16.10 Update Feb 8 Broke Wifi

Tags: wireless, updates, 16.10

No wireless device found. Wired internet only.

```
$ sudo modprobe wl
FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic
```

What?

Also, at the same time, I can no longer boot into Windows, perhaps this Ubuntu update also wrecked my Windows partition? What next?

Overnight, ethernet lost the ability to actually load web pages. It will still say connected to the internet in the icon, but cant load any web pages. Can ping 8.8.8.8. This is exasperating. Fixed this emergent problem by re-doing resolv.conf a la [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470). Very strange that this emerged overnight, while the system sat idle unconnected to anything but its charger.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0023]
Kernel modules: brcmfmac
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:0704]


grep brcmfmac /etc/modprobe.d/*
nothing.

grep bcma /etc/modprobe.d/*
nothing.
```

This is insane, but, by fixing the Windows and making it bootable, and doing literally NOTHING to the Ubuntu partitions whatsoever, now the wireless works as if nothing ever went wrong. Just finds saved network at login like it always did. I have no idea how the hell Windows reached out of its partition and into Ubuntu's to make this problem happen. I'm deeply bothered by this idea, but no idea what else it could be. Obviously, nothing changes in Ubuntu while I'm in Windows Command Prompt recovering Windows, trying to Reset Windows (that failed), and then suddenly Ubuntu is magically fixed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done my good man

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe brcmfmac` output? `wl` should not be there.

Comment: sudo modprobe brcmfmac outputs nothing.

Comment: Does wifi start working after that?

Comment: No. Why would it?

Comment: Because it starts the driver that is not started according to the output.

Comment: Please add output of `grep brcmfmac /etc/modprobe.d/*` and `grep bcma /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: nothing for either.

Comment: No more ideas. Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub.

Comment: Previous kernels also show no wireless device, as i would expect. Any ideas?

Comment: No more ideas. The module does not load for some reason. I can't guess.

Comment: Is there a chance the crappy broadcom card just bit the dust? Windows remains unbootable despite following guides, and ubuntu wont recognize wireless device, but seems otherwise healthy and functional. What would you examine next?