# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG in Xubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, xubuntu, network-manager, dns

I just installed Xubuntu 17.04 with me folder from old version of xubuntu. And when I connected to Access point (DHCP) it work few times when I visit some web pages but then I got error:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG
```

my `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I've fixed the issue by hard coding the nameserver to 8.8.8.8 (google dns I think) and it's working but why the nameserver is my localhost? I've try to change connection to address only and add DNS servers in connection in network manger but the nameserver in resolve.conf is still my localhost, why? I probably will need to remove symlink and make real file with nameserver, but I want to know if there is better (simpler) solution for the issue I'm having and also why the nameserver is my localhost?

**UPDATE** I've just deleted resolv.conf symlink with a file with hard coded nameserver but after reboot I've again get symlink (but to different file) but now with localhost 127.0.1.1 as nameserver. Anybody know how to make it permanent?

**UPDATE**: when I call `systemd-resolve --status` I've got this in return:

```
Link 3 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
         DNS Servers: 23.253.163.53
                      fe80::1
```

the DNS is there, maybe it's because when it reconnect the wifi. I have this in `dmesg`:

```
[43800.343513] wlp2s0: AP 64:3e:8c:66:cb:e4 tries to chanswitch to same channel, ignore
[43800.343519] wlp2s0: cannot understand ECSA IE operating class 12, disconnecting
```

I've also try to put this in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
interface "wlp2s0" {
  supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

after this I've got more dns servers in `systemd-resolve --status` but when it reconnect (probably) then I've got the DNS error.

Comment: @Fabby I already seen this question, my is different I got this when the symlink was correct and I didn't get the error when run `resolvconf -u`

Comment: Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 1):

First... DON'T manually edit /etc/resolv.conf... it says so right in the file... 'cause your manual edits WILL get overwritten. Also, DON'T start deleting symlinks/etc if you don't know what they do.

The proper way to add DNS servers is to edit your connection profile. Go to the IPv4 Settings tab, change the popup to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only", and place your DNS servers in a comma-separated list where it says "DNS Servers".

[image]

**Update #1** - from [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04) with corrections

In `terminal`...

```
sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: I've already try that and I still get the local server as the only nameserver in resolv.conf

Comment: What do you get in `terminal` when you type `ps auxc | grep dns`?

Comment: `kuba      4114  0.0  0.0  72208  7068 ?        Sl   22:00   0:00 gvfsd-dnssd`

Comment: How about `grep -i dns /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?

Comment: got nothing in return

Comment: That's the correct answer. Resolv.conf should show `nameserver 127.0.0.53`, but you've changed something in your config. They've also made some DNS changes in 17.04, and I haven't got it all figured out how it's glued together now. If you setup your network profile exactly as I said, then I don't have any more ideas for you at this time.

Comment: I think I had `127.0.0.53` before I've removed the symlink and then it got replaced by another symlink.

Comment: The `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` should show `resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Comment: See update #1 in my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: No, it don't, I've did try it when you've commented the symlink path, and I have this error before I removed the symlink, so it's not it.

Comment: Does `cat /etc/resolv.conf` show "nameserver 127.0.0.53"? And did you do ALL of the commands in my update?

Comment: yes, but I just remove the file again nad make it read only, maybe that will be a workaround for me.

Comment: You didn't answer my two questions. And ro on that file isn't the correct answer either.

Comment: I've answered the questions, recreating the symlink didin't help and it was showing the 127.0.0.53, but I was having dns error. so I've remove the file again.