# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Tags: networking, dns

I've *DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG* issue.

I did try the methods given on these 2 links:

1. [dns-probe-finished-bad-config-in-xubuntu-17-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905143/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-in-xubuntu-17-04)
2. [dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04)

but no difference. I am still getting that problem. I did these codes:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

and then

```
sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

and also rebooted.

The terminal did not show any sort of failure, or as much as I know.

Finally also installed dnsq packacge, (sorry I don't rememeber) but still facing the problem.

Comment: Please run the command: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i dns` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Try this one - it might help in your case! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045682/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error