# 17.04 and DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Tags: networking, internet, dns, 17.04

I have issue on Ubuntu 17.04, Internet works fine and after a few minutes, sometimes hours suddenly it stops working.
Also sometimes when I run the system in the morning, the internet is not working from the beginning.

In both cases I have message in chrome browse:

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Worth to add, I can ping ip adress. For e.g ping wp.pl - not working but ping 212.77.100.101 - working.

Also internet in this time working fine on other devices - android smartphone, desktop PC with OpenMandriva or even on the same device but on other OS - Fedora 25. So look like this is bug in Ubuntu 17.04, but I can't fix it.
For Ubuntu 17.04 help me only restarting router...

I trying fix it like in this topic: [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04)

but any solution not working for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -i dns` If the result is lenthy, post the output here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/622493) may help you.

Summary:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Then refresh your browser or others.

Comment: psst. dont forget `cp /etc/resolv.conf ~/` so that resolv.conf is backed up