# Ubuntu could not connect to home WiFi

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, internet, dns

My laptop(running Ubuntu 18) could not connect to home WiFi.
I tried searching for the answer but none of them helped.

I keep on getting dns probe finished bad config and other dns related error or could not connect to internet on chrome.

when doing ping on google.com almost 80% packets are lost.
I checked by router and there are no blocked MAC addresses. I tried resetting the router but that also didn't help. WiFi works good on my phone but not on laptop.

When i connect my laptop to my office WiFi it just works fine. The problem persists on my home WiFi.

some of the solution I tried

- [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04)
- Setting `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Have you installed the correct drivers? I can't begin to guess what the NIC is.

Comment: I installed fresh Ubuntu and also the WiFi works in my office. The problem is in my home network. So I think the drivers are installed or you can tell me how to check if i have correct drivers?

Comment: can someone help me?